# Reindex Sunspot Solr in Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sunspot, sunspot-solr, rvm-capistrano

I'm following this snippet for adding Sunspot Solr in Capistrano https://gist.github.com/doitian/1795439 and it works, but when I run cap solr:reindex it shows a question (as expected) asking if I want to drop all indexes, so I answer with "yes" but the terminal seems to be waiting for a response.

This is the code for the reindex:

```
  desc "reindex the whole database"
  task :reindex, :roles => :app do
    stop
    run "rm -rf #{shared_path}/solr/data"
    start
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} sunspot:solr:reindex" 
  end
```

This is the message:

```
  * executing "cd /home/user/rapps/app/current && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production sunspot:solr:reindex"
    servers: ["9.9.9.9"]
    [9.9.9.9] executing command
 ** [out :: 9.9.9.9] *Note: the reindex task will remove your current indexes and start from scratch.
 ** [out :: 9.9.9.9] If you have a large dataset, reindexing can take a very long time, possibly weeks.
 ** [out :: 9.9.9.9] This is not encouraged if you have anywhere near or over 1 million rows.
 ** [out :: 9.9.9.9] Are you sure you want to drop your indexes and completely reindex? (y/n)
y
```

How can avoid that message? Also, I will like to run this rake with Cron so how could I previously give the answer or set a default configuration? And what is the best/efficient way to reindex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the sunspot_rails source, there currently is no way to **force** your way past this message. See [the rake task code defined here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb)

There has been a pull request submitted (a month ago) [(Pull request here)](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/370) for the rake task to support a *silent* option, but it has not been merged yet.

I would either:

1. Fork the sunspot gem [Repo located here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) and make the changes yourself to the rake task (then change your environment Gemfile to use your forked gem).
2. Add a sleep command to your Capistrano task (something like 10 seconds, longer then it should ever take for this command to appear), and then provide the standard input with "y"

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem recently and found this to be a useful workaround:

```
yes | bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

Answer (score 4):

The [pull request](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/370) has now been merge on the sunspot gem. You should be able to use `rake sunspot:reindex[,,true]` to trigger a silence reindex.

Once again [memes save the planet](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/370#issuecomment-16323471).